# Code optimization

Tags: c++, optimization

When i'm trying to optimize my code, I often run into a dilemma:

I have an expression like this:

```
int x = 5 + y * y;
int z = sqrt(12) + y * y;
```

Does it worth it making a new integer variable to store y*y for two instances, or just leave them alone?

```
int s = y* y;
int x = 5 + s;
int z = sqrt(12) + s;
```

If not, how many instances does it need to worth it?

Comment: Unless you are looking for best guess answers, find out for yourself by profiling both examples.

Comment: This is an incredibly trivial optimization, which your compiler will probably do anyways.

Comment: Turn on optimizations and look at the generated assembly to see if there's any difference.

Comment: What are you optimizing for?
Generally, your target for optimization should be clarity of code, not squeezing out cycles. In almost every case, developer time is much more expensive than CPU time.

Comment: Typically something like this is less of a speed/memory optimization, and more of a readability optimization. saying `int s = y*y` is more readable (IMHO), especially if you use `s` frequently. Neither imlpementation will be significantly better space or time usage

Comment: Unless you've profile your code and determined that this is a bottleneck, there's a 99% chance that you are wasting your time. In your compiler you should trust.

Comment: @wlyles Whether it is more or less readable depends on whether the two subexpressions are intrinsically identical, or simply coincidentally identical, and whether you can find a good name for the intermediate value.

Comment: @JamesKanze good point. Just because two things happen to be equal, making a new variable in the code for them might not be a good idea if they are actually unrelated, as this could lead to more confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the older compiler optimisations is "common subexpression elimination" - in this case `y * y` is such a common subexpression.

It may still make sense to show a reader of the code that the expression only needs calculating once, but any compiler produced in the last ten years will calculate this perfectly fine without repeating the multiplication.

Trying to "beat the compiler on it's own game" is often futile, and certainly needs measuring to ensure you get a better result than the compiler. Adding extra variables MAY cause the compiler to produce worse code, because it gets "confused", so it may not help at all.

And ALWAYS when it comes to performance (or code size) results from varying optimizations, measure, measure again, and measure a third time to make sure you get the results you expect. It's not very easy to predict from looking at code which is faster, and which is slower. But it'd definitely be surprised if `y * y` is calculated twice even with a low level of optimisation in your compiler.

Answer (score 4):

Trying to optimize your code most often means giving the compiler the permission (through flags) to do its own optimization. Trying to do it yourself will more often then not, either just be a waste of time (no improvement over the compiler) or worse.

In your specific example, I seriously doubt there is anything you can do to change the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a temporary variable:

```
int z = y * y;
int x = z + 5
z = z + sqrt(12);
```

but the only way to be sure if this is (a) faster and (b) truly where you should focus your attention, is to use a profiler and benchmark your entire application.